# Sending information through a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

At the moment I'm making another html5/javascript ad. This one uses multiple data from cookies. In order to render everything properly I have made a for-loop that gets the information and then sends it to another function afterwards.

My problem is that it loads too quick the first time so it skips the images. Each time I have to refresh the ad before it shows properly. All the onload functions I have used failed so far (sending the wrong data, nothing at all or only 1 piece of it).

Here is the relevant part of the project:

```
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){
   pT.push("pT"+[i]);
   pM.push("pM"+[i]);
   ctx.push("ctxP"+[i]);
   cvs.push("cvsP"+[i]);

   cvs[i] = document.getElementById('canvas'+[i]);
   ctx[i] = cvs[i].getContext('2d');

   pT[i] =  new Image();
   pT[i].onload = function(){
       console.log("pT: "+ this.height);
   }
   pT[i].src = data.products[i].imageUrl;

   pM[i] =  new Image();
   pM[i].onload = function(){
       console.log("pM: "+ this.height);
   }
   pM[i].src = data.products[i].imageUrl;

   testing(pT[i], pM[i]);
}

function testing(pThumb, pMain){
   console.log(pThumb.height);
}
```

What I want is a method so all the information gets send when everything is done loading.

Comment: did you try to use onload listener?

Comment: Yes I have, it resulted in the rest of the data not to process properly and when I tried to fix that, it would only send 1 part of the array and not the rest. It could be that I have used it in the wrong way/position though, I'm still learning :).

Answer (score 0):

```
pT[i].onload = function() { 
    alert("Image is Loaded, do you thing on the image here");
}



otherFunction(pT,pM);
function otherFunction(pT,pM) {
    console.log(pT,pM);
}




pT[i] =  new Image();
pT[i].onload = function(){
   pM[i] =  new Image();
   pM[i].onload = function(){
       console.log("pM: "+ this.height);
       testing(pT[i], pM[i]);
   }
} 
pT[i].src = data.products[i].imageUrl;
pM[i].src = data.products[i].imageUrl; // this is very ugly but you'll be sure to call your function when both image are ready. Since i'm not the best with Canvas, I will accept any edit for a better code.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this and it would work usually but in this case it wont (yet). In the for-loop itself I don't do anything with the image besides loading and assigning it. At the end of the loop  it gets send to another function where it gets drawn, animated, re-sized etc.

Comment: I'm guessing something, did you set the onload **after** or **before** the **.src = data.products[i].imageUrl** ??

Comment: pT[i] = new Image();
    pT[i].src = data.products[i].imageUrl;
    pt[i].onload = function(){
      console.log('like this');
    }  *edit* Ughh can't get the mark-up right of this comment

Comment: You have to set the onload **BEFORE** setting the source

Comment: Really? I thought it was after. I'll try it before this time. How would I make this so that it also sends the 3 different image data to the next function? That part is what has been bottle-necking me.

Comment: You can directly send the array of image to the other function 
See edit answer for code.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand this right this will send the whole array to the other function. Is it also possible to use the method I was using before, sending each image separate along with the rest of the info (see the last line in my original code). I'm sorry if I'm a bit slow and understanding this all but I'm trying here ;)

Comment: Ok so, I have been trying with your input in mind. The onload does work, it returns the correct height of the image when I test it (would be 0 if it didn't load correctly). But I'm still missing something in my code obviously. It's still sending the unloaded image data first. How do I get around this? I'll edit my original code to what it is now for easier use.

Comment: New code is up. For clarification, the log in the called function (pThumb.height) returns 0. It's getting the wrong data.

Comment: Try setting the source of image in the onload, and call the function "testing" at the end of the second onload. Because the onload anonymous function will trigger only when the image is loaded, during this time, the javascript continue to execute, so what is happening is that your function testing is getting called before the image is loaded

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I understand how the onload works but I think there are too many conflicting elements to pull this off. So I guess I'm going to let it rest for a bit and try a different approach later on. Thank for the help though! It's really appreciated.

Comment: Well I didn't want to suggest that because it's ugly and i'm the best one with canvas but you can try the third code in my answer